# Show that two groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

$$\varphi : \mathbb{C}^{*}/\mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \ S =  \left \{ z\in {C}^{*}: |z|=1 \right \}$$

So far, I've done this: $\phi : \mathbb{C}^{*} \to S$ where $\phi(z)=|z|$. $\phi$ is a homomorphism and is surjective, since for every z in S there is a z in $\mathbb{C}^{*}$. Therefore, $S\simeq \mathbb{C}^{*}/\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. 
Is this proof sufficient? I also have a feeling I defined $\phi$ wrong.

I would appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure with the formula? Since for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ $|z| \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, but $|z| \not\in S$ in general.

Comment: Also, how do I show that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is ker($\varphi$)?

Comment: If you know the first fundamental theorem for group homomorphisms you're done: $G/\text{kernel}$ is isomorphic to the image.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I used to conclude that they are isomorphic. Do I have to show that R is the kernel though?

Comment: As defined in the question, $\;\phi\;$ doesn't even map to $\;S\;$ ... For example, $\;\phi(2i):=|2i|=2\notin S\;$ .

Comment: Could it be you *actually meant* $\;\phi:C^*\to\Bbb R^+\;,\;\;\phi(z):=|z|\;$ ? In this case, we'd have $\;\ker\phi=S\;$ ...

Comment: I think you may have the question backwards. The absolute value map has the positive reals for the image. The unit circle is the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but the wrong $\phi$. The map you've defined doesn't even land in the right place! $2\in\Bbb C^\times$, but $\left|2\right| = 2\not\in S^1$.

The map I think you intended is the map projecting each infinite ray from the origin in $\Bbb C^\times$ to the unique element on the ray with absolute value one: this map is given by
\begin{align*}
\phi : \Bbb C^\times&\to S^1\\
z&\mapsto\frac{z}{\left|z\right|}.
\end{align*}

Now this is a surjective group homomorphism (exercise), and we have
\begin{align*}
\ker\phi &= \{z\in\Bbb C^\times\mid\phi(z) = 1\}\\
&= \{z\in\Bbb C^\times\mid z/\left|z\right| = 1\}\\
&= \{z\in\Bbb C^\times\mid z = \left|z\right|\}\\
&= \Bbb R^+.
\end{align*}

So, by the first isomorphism theorem, $\Bbb C^\times/\Bbb R^+\cong S^1$.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! I just always struggle to define the function correctly!

Comment: The first sanity check you should do is make sure your map is a) well-defined and b) actually a map between the groups you want - once you have a bonafide homomorphism that lands in the right place, you're usually not too far off from the solution. If it doesn't work, you can think about where the map failed and try to modify it so that it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a good answer. Here's an overview that may explain the confusion in the statement of the problem.

Writing nonzero complex numbers in polar form as $re^{i\theta}$ essentially establishes an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}^*$ and the direct product $\mathbb{R}^+ \times S^1$. The projections onto each factor exhibit each factor as the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^*$ modulo the other factor.

Comment: @lhf Fixed thanks